# How do I write regex to exclude words contained inside a file?

Tags: regex, typescript, nsregularexpression

I want to perform email validation, which excludes emails of popular domains. As a reference, I am using email domains from here: https://github.com/mailcheck/mailcheck/wiki/List-of-Popular-Domains. I am planning to put them inside a resource file.

How do I write a regex, which will exclude the emails, ending on these domains (i.e. which will exclude ending on the words from this file)?

I want to write it in typescript, if this matters.

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? What did you get? What did you expect?
What doesn't work with your code and where is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is a negative lookaround.

(I'm gonna simplify the first part of the regex so it's easily understandable)

```
^([^@]*@(?!gmail.com|aol.com|mailinator.com|...)[^@]*?$)
```

However, since you would have to programmatically build this string, and it would be a huge regex, you might want to consider other options like parsing the `@...` bit of your input and doing a simple: `arrayOfDomains.indexOf(thisDomain) > -1` to detect if it's included in the list